# A perfect square and a perfect cube: is it also a perfect sixth power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

As the title suggests:

Prove that for any natural number, if it is a perfect square and a perfect cube, it is also a perfect sixth power.

For some reason I just have hit a road block on this question.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you convert the sentences into mathematical statements?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $n$ is an integer such that $n = a^2 = b^3$ for some integers $a, b$.

Let $p$ be any prime.

How many times does $p$ divide $n$?

Can you show that it must be a multiple of $6$?

Hence conclude that $n$ must be of the form $c^6$, i.e. a perfect sixth power.

Answer (score 1):

Without los of generality we can assume that $a,b >0$.

Let $x= \sqrt[6]{n}$. Then $x^2=b$ and $x^3=a$. Thus

$$x=\frac{x^3}{x^2}=\frac{a}{b}\,.$$

As $x$ is rational, we can write it in the reduced form $x=\frac{c}{d}$ with $\gcd(c,d)=1$. Then $x^6=\frac{c^6}{d^6}=n$ implies that $d^6|c^6$.

Now prove that $\gcd(c^6,d^6)=1$ to conclude that $d^6=1$, which shows that $x$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the prime factorization of your number.

If it a perfect square, what do you know about the exponent on each of the prime factors?

If it a perfect cube, what do you know about the exponent on each of the prime factors?

So, now what ***combined*** simple fact  do you know about the exponent on each prime factor?