# Show that a cube number which is also a square is of the form 7n, 7n+1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I cannot reach at the answer but I have done the following:
$N^6= (N^2)^3= (N^3)^2$
Using a derivation of Fermat's theorem $(N^\frac{p-1}{2} +1)(N^\frac{p-1}{2} -1)=kp$
Taking p=13, I got $N^6=13k+1, 13k-1$
How to reach the asked conclusion ?

Comment: You are correct that $N^6 = 13k \pm 1$ but that really is too weak a result.  You are using too weak a consequence  of FLT.  Use FLT *directly*  $N^6 = N^{7-1} \equiv 1,0 \mod 7$.  Much more applicable.

Comment: Your first line shows that if an integer is a sixth power then it's a cube and a square.  But if you are going to apply Fermat's Theorem to 6th powers to address the problem in your title, you need to show the converse, that is, if $x = y^2 = z^3$, then $x$ is a sixth power.

Comment: A proof that if an integer is both a square and a cube then it is a sixth power of an integer may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367032/a-natural-number-that-is-both-a-perfect-square-and-a-perfect-cube-is-a-perfect-s).

Answer (score 2):

The squares mod $7$ are $0,1,2,4$.

The cubes mod $7$ are $0,1,6$.

The intersection of these two sets is $0,1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p=7$ which by Fermat's little theorem, divides $n^p-n=n(n^{p-1}-1)$ for all integer $n$

Now consider the two cases
$p| n$

and $p\nmid n$

Answer (score 1):

If $7\not| N$ then $gcd(7,N)=1$, so $ N^{7-1}\equiv 1(mod\  7)\Rightarrow N^6=7n+1$

If $7|N \Rightarrow 7|N^6\Rightarrow N^6=7n$

Answer (score 0):

Why use the prime $13$ and the derivation of FLT when you can use the prime $7$ and FLT itself?

$N^{7-1}\equiv 1 \mod 7$ if $7\not \mid a$. (i.e. $N^6$ is of the form $N^6 = 7n + 1$

... and...

$N^{7-1} \equiv 0\mod 7$ if $7\mid N$. (i.e. $N^6$ is of the form $N^6 = 7n$).

So any number that is both a square and a cube is a sixth power and the result follows.